# how can i check if a readline is closed node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to make a simple script that detects if a readline was closed, and if it wasn't, it would close it.

preferably there would be a solution that works something like this:

```js
if(!readline.isClosed){

    readline.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to listen to the `close` event of `readline interface`

```
const readline = require('node:readline');
const { stdin: input, stdout: output } = require('node:process');

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});

rl.on("close",()=>{
    console.log("read line closed"); // Will be called when readline is closed
})
```

Look [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#event-close)

See [working](https://app.codingrooms.com/w/wlp1BmKQp6p4)

Comment: the problem is that i want to make a system where it closes the rl IF it's not closed, NOT do something after it was closed

Comment: because i want to disable the readline, run `shell.exec(\`git push\`)` and readline steals the input if not closed